# VB.NET - Number of Combobox Items should be based on the number of records in the database

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem here on `vb.net`.

I have a program here connected to a database with fields (`id` , `name`, `quantity`) on table `tbl_report`

Part of my program is to delete a record that has an `ID` equals to the selected item of `cbOrderNo`

The items of cbOrderNo are the IDs from the table. So when a record is deleted, items of `cbOrderNo` supposedly will be deducted.

So for example, there are 4 records in the table so during the form load there will be 4 items in `cbOrderNo` and when the user selects 1 of the items in the combobox, a record will be deleted so 3 records will be left and so as 3 items in `cbOrderNo`

What my program is doing is that after 3 records are left, there will still be 4 items in the combobox. What I want is to show only 3 items there.

```
Dim qryDelete As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_report WHERE ID=" & cbOrderNo.SelectedItem & ""
ExecNonQuery(qryDelete)
MsgBox("Record Deleted")
query.Close()

cbOrderNo.Items.Clear()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_report ORDER BY ID"
cmd.Connection = con
Dim rdrOLEDB As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
While(rdrOLEDB.Read())
     cbOrderNo.Items.Add(rdrOLEDB.GetValue(0))
    MsgBox(cbOrderNo.Items.Count)
End While
MsgBox(cbOrderNo.Items.Count)
cbOrderNo.SelectedIndex = 0
rdrOLEDB.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Dim qryDelete As String = "DELETE FROM tbl_report WHERE ID=" & cbOrderNo.SelectedItem & ""
ExecNonQuery(qryDelete)
MsgBox("Record Deleted")
query.Close()

cbOrderNo.Items.Remove(cbOrderNo.SelectedItem) 'there is no point in recalling the database, just remove it from the list.
```

Comment: Wow! I haven't considered doing that. Thanks APrough. It worked.